# Polynomial has roots in any ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

I have to prove that the polynomial
$$(X^2-13)(X^2-17)(X^2-221)$$
has roots in all rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $221 = 13\cdot 17$, we can use the multiplicativity of the Legendre-symbol if $n$ is prime and see that $\left(\frac{13\cdot 17 }{n}\right), \left(\frac{13}{n}\right), \left(\frac{17}{n}\right)$ can't all be $-1$.

But for general $n$ I am stuck. If I use the Chinese remainder theorem, I still have to show that the polynomial has roots modulo a *power* of a prime number.

Comment: What book has this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to know that, for $p$ an odd prime, if $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$ has a solution, with $(a,p)=1$, then $x^2\equiv a\pmod {p^k}$ has a solution for any $k$. This is shown via induction relatively easily for $p$ odd.

The case of powers of $2$ is a little harder. You actually need to start with $x^2\equiv a\pmod{8}$ before the induction works.

Comment: This process is generally known, incidentally, as _Hensel lifting_ and you should have luck searching under that name to see the details.

Comment: I kind of deliberately left that name out because it is a good exercise to see how it works yourself. It is a fairly neat process.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Maybe even one may call it power series expansion rather than induction. I mean the idea is that since some power of $p$ vanishes, $p$ may be viewed as an ideally behaving variable making all kinds of power series converge (well at least the ones with coefficients whose denominators are not divisible by $p$...)

Comment: No, it's really not power series. I've seen it described as Newton's formula (which is more accurate.) @მამუკაჯიბლაძე

Comment: The hard part is the powers of $2$...

Comment: what does $(a,p) = 1$ mean?

Comment: That they are relatively prime. @user223635 Really just means, here, that $p$ does not divide $a$.

Comment: The gcd? b/c it doesn't work for $x^2 = 2 \bmod{2^k}$.

Comment: Because $\gcd(2,2)\neq 1$.

Comment: then what shall I do for higher powers of 13 and 17?

Comment: You only need one term divisible by $p$. So $x^2\equiv 17\pmod{13}$ has a solution, as does $x^2\equiv 13\pmod{17}$. @user223635

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes thank you. Could it be put like this - even if denominators **are** divisible by $p$ one still can do it in case the power of $p$ dividing these denominators does not grow too fast so one can cancel it with the power of the variable? And then rigorously/consistently one may perform this using (something like) Newton's formula, i. e. invoking derivatives...

Comment: What denominators? There are no fractions here. @მამუკაჯიბლაძე

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I mean, e. g. in a particular case of this particular problem, denominators of $\binom{1/2}n$ which occur in the Taylor series for $(1+t)^{1/2}$

Comment: Again, this methodology has nothing to do with Taylor expansions. @მამუკაჯიბლაძე

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry I was not asking clearly then - I meant to ask whether it can be done using Taylor expansions.

Comment: I don't think it will, but you can keep trying. @მამუკაჯიბლაძე

Comment: So it seems that when you exchange the "17" with "5" the polynomial hasn't solutions modulo for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ anymore, e. g. no solution in $\mathbb{Z}/125\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews OK let me try

Comment: Note that $221$ is one of the smallest odd (squarefree) numbers for which we are a bit surprised that $x^2 - 221 y^2 = -1$ is not possible in integers. Only $205$ is smaller. Smallest of all is $34,$ as $x^2 - 34 y^2 = -1$ is impossible. In Gouvea, $p$-adic Numbers, page 79, he gives this exercise with $$ (x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 17)(x^2 - 34).  $$ Result (very short proof) in Mordell's book that for prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ $x^2 - p y^2 = -1$ always has an integer solution.

Comment: Well, little exercise for myself, trying to see what is wrong, for example, with $(x^2-5)(x^2-13)(x^2-65)$ as $65 \equiv 1 \pmod 8.$ Trouble seems to be, entirely, that $5,13$ are mutual quadratic NON-residues.

Comment: Yes, fpr $(x-a)(x-b)(x-ab)$ with $a,b$ relatively prime, you need $a$ a square modulo $b$, $b$ a square modulo $a$ and one of $a,b,ab\equiv 1\pmod 8$. @WillJagy

Comment: Thomas, thanks. So $ (x^2-5)(x^2-41)(x^2 - 205) $ also works.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I definitely don't want to compete with the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1200582/214353) by Thomas Andrews, it is definitely **the** answer, I just want to try and see whether it can be also done using Taylor series.

As he points out, powers of 2 are trickier. For odd $p$, we can proceed as follows.

We are given integers $x$ and $c$ with $a=x^2+cp$ and we are looking for $y$ with $y^2\equiv a\pmod{p^k}$. Thus we need
$$
\sqrt a=\sqrt{x^2+cp}=x\sqrt{1+\frac{cp}{x^2}}
$$
and my claim is that computing this analytically via power series expansion **makes sense in $\mathbb Z/p^k$**.

First, since $a$ is not divisible by $p$, neither is $x$, so $1/x$ (and then also $1/x^2$) "exists in $\mathbb Z/p^k$". More precisely, there is an integer $x'$ with $xx'\equiv1\pmod{p^k}$ and I will simply denote this $x'$ by $1/x$.

Let us now expand $x(1+\frac c{x^2}p)^{\frac12}$ into Taylor series treating $p$ as a variable:
$$
x(1+\frac c{x^2}p)^{\frac12}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\frac12}n\left(\frac c{x^2}p\right)^n=x+\frac c{2x}p-\frac{c^2}{8x^3}p^2+\frac{c^3}{16x^5}p^3-\frac{5c^4}{128x^7}p^4+...+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\binom{2n}nx}{2n-1}\left(\frac c{4x^2}\right)^np^n+...
$$
(see e. g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficient_with_n_.3D_.C2.BD)). Now in fact $\frac{\binom{2n}n}{2n-1}$ is an integer (it is twice the $n-1$st [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)), and also $1/4$ can be replaced by an integer -- let us just denote by $1/4$ some integer $d$ with $4d\equiv1\pmod{p^k}$. So this series makes sense and converges in $\mathbb Z/p^k$ to a certain value $y$. Actually we just throw out all powers of $p$ starting from $p^k$ and obtain an integer $y$ (rememeber $1/x$ is also a notation for a certain integer). Then by the very construction $y^2\equiv a\pmod{p^k}$.

I admit I am too lazy to work out details for $p=2$ but one thing I can say is that if given a solution of $x^2\equiv a\pmod2$ I can find a solution of $x^2\equiv a\pmod 8$ then the higher powers of 2 can be treated similarly to the above: if $a=x^2+8c$ then $\sqrt a=x\sqrt{1+\frac{4cp}{x^2}}$ where $p=2$, and we can give sense to the expansion of $\sqrt{1+\frac{4cp}{x^2}}$ in $\mathbb Z/2^k$ since the resulting series will only have odd denominators (well, no denominators at all actually, as $1/x$ just denotes some integer).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This is what I had in mind.

Comment: As an example: suppose we take $p=7, a=2$; then $x=3$, $c=-1$.  $\frac{1}{2x}=\frac16\equiv41\equiv-8$, and so the relevant terms of the series give $x+\frac{c}{2x}p$=$3+(-1)(-8)7=59\equiv 10\pmod {49}$, and clearly $10^2=100=2\cdot98+2\equiv 2\pmod {49}$.

Comment: One small catch with this approach, incidentally, is that while it computes the solution for any given $p^k$, it doesn't really _transfer_ the solution from $p^k$ to $p^{k+1}$; many of the values to hand (and in particular, $\frac{c}{4x^2}$) must be recomputed for each stage of the process since they'll be different (though also 'lifted') $\mod p^{k+1}$ than they were $\mod p^k$.  Also, this approach is really limited to roots, whereas the lifting version works for (almost) arbitrary polynomial equations (and also gives criteria for when and how it fails).

Comment: That said, this is a great alternative perspective on the problem, and a well-deserved upvote from me.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks. Actually a proper way to do it is probably in $p$-adics. I believe computing the same series there with Teichmüller representatives will produce a single solution which is good for all $p^k$ at once.

Comment: In order that you can do this, you really ought to be working in the $p$-adic numbers. Otherwise, the taylor series doesn't work. For example, what inverse of $x^2$ are you using? What ring are you computing this series in? In the end, this is about $p$-adics.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well yes, I acknowledged that in the end I need $\mathbb Z_p$ - there is no single integer I could choose for an inverse of $x^2$ that would work for all $\mathbb Z/p^k$ simultaneously. On the other hand for each fixed $k$ I can choose its own inverse and proceed as stated.

Comment: (And a collection of such choices for each $k$ is none other than a $p$-adic number)

Comment: ((And I also find significant that for $p=2$ the same 8 pops up naturally, although seemingly for an entirely different reason))

Comment: As for the ring where I am computing - for fixed $k$ either in $\mathbb Z/p^k$ or in $\mathbb Z$.