# Does there exist an integer $b$ such that $f(b) = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $f(X)$ be a monic polynomial with integer coefficients and let $p$ be an odd prime number.
Now suppose that for every positive integer $m$, there exists an integer $a$ such that $f(a) ≡ 0 \pmod{p^m}$.
Does that mean then that there exists an integer $b$ such that $f(b) = 0$?

I know this involves Hensel's Lemma but I'm not sure about the last statement. Is that true or not? If not, what's a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true, not even if you require the existence of a root mod $n$ for all $n$.

For instance,
$(X^2-13)(X^2-17)(X^2-221)$
has roots mod $n$ for all $n$ but it has no integer root.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200578/polynomial-has-roots-in-any-ring-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-but-not-in-mathbbz.