# Prove that $x^3 + 118x^2 +24x = 1003$ has no solutions in the integers.

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

I am having trouble with the mark scheme's approach to the following problem:

Prove that $x^3 + 118x^2 +24x = 1003$ has no integer solutions.

The mark scheme attempts to prove this by contradiction, by reducing the polynomial modulo 3 and then showing that a solution in mod 3 does not exist:

"We obtain: $[x]^3+[x]^2 =1 $ which clearly has no solutions for $x =0, 1, 2$. Hence there are no solutions modulo 3 and no integer solutions".

First of all, this modulo issue is confusing to me as I've practically never done it before. Why are we allowed to do this?

However, this is what confuses me the most:

I reduce the polynomial modulo 2 to obtain:

$[x]^3=1$ which does have solutions in mod 2!! What is going on here? (I might have made a mistake, but I dont know what it is).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The polynomial not having roots when reduced in some modulo is a sufficient condition for the original polynomial not having roots.

Comment: You only need for one modulo to fail in order to conclude that the equation has no solutions.Since if $a=b$ then $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ or in other words $a\not\equiv b\pmod{n}\implies a\not= b$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider polynomial equations with integer coefficients. Then

> If an equation has a solution in the integers, then it has a solution mod $m$ for all $m$.

This follows because reduction mod $m$ respects addition and multiplication.

An equivalent formulation is given by the contrapositive:

> If an equation doesn't have a solution mod $m$ for *some* $m$, then it can't have a solution in the integers.

So it suffices to exhibit one $m$ for which the equation has no solution mod $m$.
It does not mean that all $m$ will work. In your example, $m=3$ works but $m=2$ doesn't.

On the other hand, reducing mod $m$ does not always work at all.
Indeed, the equation $$(x^2 − 13)(x^2 − 17)(x^2 − 221)=0$$ has no solution in the integers, but it has a solution mod $m$ for all $m$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200578/polynomial-has-roots-in-any-ring-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-but-not-in-mathbbz).

Comment: Although your the only one who is following the approach of reduction mod $m $, I don't think OP knows what a ring homomorphism is.

Comment: @Xammm, thanks for the nudge.

Comment: Ok, thanks! @lhf

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try to use [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)